# Create a square matrix with random integer value generate

Tags: c

I am trying to create a random square matrix (based on the user's input) with elements that are generated randomly. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generate_random (int lower, int upper);

int main ()
{
    int upper,lower,i,j,M,N,matrix[M][N];
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);
    printf("Enter the range of random numbers:\nUpper: ");
    scanf("%d",&upper);
    printf("Lower: ");
    scanf("%d",&lower);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = generate_random(lower,upper);
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int generate_random (int lower, int upper)
{
    int rand_num;
    rand_num = (rand()%(upper-lower+1))+1;
    return rand_num;
}
```

However, I get a very strange output and quite don't understand why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEPBX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIgN.png)

Please help me with this. I'm new to C and really confused right now.

Comment: Please do not post text output as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it directly as formatted text into the question.

Comment: `matrix[M][N];` The `M` and `N` values are unintialised at that point. You can only validly use them *after* reading in the values.

Comment: @kaylum thank you for helping me with this question. However, I haven't really understood what I need to do with the code. Can you please be more specific on what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here in declaration part

```
int upper,lower,i,j,M,N,matrix[M][N];
```

`M` and `N` is not defined will give `segmentation fault`. Input the value for `M` & `N` first then create the **matrix**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generate_random (int lower, int upper);

int main (){
    int M,N;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);
    int upper,lower,i,j,matrix[M][N];
    printf("Enter the range of random numbers:\nUpper: ");
    scanf("%d",&upper);
    printf("Lower: ");
    scanf("%d",&lower);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = generate_random(lower,upper);
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int generate_random (int lower, int upper)
{
    int rand_num;
    rand_num = (rand()%(upper-lower+1))+1;
    return rand_num;
}
```

### Output:

```
$ gcc randgen.c && ./a.out
Enter the number of rows and columns: 
5
5
Enter the range of random numbers:
Upper: 10
Lower: 3
8 8 5 7 2 
6 7 5 4 1 
5 1 7 1 7 
3 6 4 7 5 
3 1 8 6 4
```

Comment: Thank you Dev Parzival and @kaylum for helping me with this question so fast and clearly. Hope you guys have a great day.

Comment: Note, ALL user input must be validated or you invite *undefined behavior*, e.g. `if (scanf("%d %d",&M,&N) != 2) { /* handle error */ }` That applies to all inputs. Also worth mentioning `int matrix[M][N];` creates a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) that is distinct and different from an array created with literal integer constants, e.g. `int matrix[4][4];` Compiler support for VLA's are optional beginning with C11 -- though I don't know of any major compiler that won't provide support -- at least through compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

How to generate a random integer in a desired range (caveats apply) using `rand()`:

```
int random( int min, int max )
{
  int N = max - min + 1;             // N ⟵ magnitude of output range where 1 < N ≤ (RAND_MAX+1)
  int K = ((RAND_MAX + 1) / N) * N;  // K ⟵ k × N where k = maximum integer such that kN ≤ (RAND_MAX+1)
  int n;                             // 
  do n = rand(); while (n >= K);     // (discard unwanted pigeons)
  return (n % N) + min;              // n ⟶ output range
}
```